# How to check if params exist in rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

This works, but feels klunky. Is there a more rails-y way to limit a collection based on params?  I'm using active model serializers gem and need the json response to be limited via the params.

```
def index    
 if params.has_key?(:limit)
   limit = params[:limit].to_i
   @pages = Page.all.take(limit)
 else
   @pages = Page.all
 end
end
```

If I use the following, I receive error messages when passing a string or nothing to the limit params.

```
def index
 @pages = Page.limit(params[:limit])

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @pages }
 end
```

end

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't have to do anything. Just pass params[:limit] in directly.

```
def index
  @page = Page.limit(params[:limit])
end
```

If params[:limit] isn't defined (nil), it'll just return all of the records. You don't even need to convert it to an integer. Rails does it for you!

**UPDATE**

If you really want to check that non-numbers aren't being passed in, you could create your own limit class method in your Page class (not tested, but should work):

```
class Page << ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.limit(num = nil)
    num = num.to_i > 0 ? num : nil
    super(num)
  end

end
```

Comment: I thought so, but I'm getting errors. I'm using active model serializers gem to convert to json. here's the rest of the controller:     
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @pages }
    end

Comment: If I try the URL: http://localhost:3000/pages.json?limit=aaaa
I get the error: invalid value for Integer(): "aaaa"

Thanks